# 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' in Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function running locally in dev mode. I am trying to import `node-fetch`:

```
import { fetch } from "node-fetch";

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  const res = await fetch("https://www.swyx.io/api/rss.xml");

  const responseMessage = "res:" + res.ok;

  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: responseMessage,
  };
};
```

I get the following error:

```
Worker was unable to load function HttpTrigger1: 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'
```

What I've tried:

1. I added `type: 'module'` to package.json.
2. I named the file `index.cjs`

But it still throws same error.

For reference, here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cors-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And here is the file structure:

```
.
├── host.json
├── HttpTrigger1
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── index.cjs
│   └── sample.dat
├── local.settings.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [the solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#ecmascript-modules)

1. renamed the file to index.mjs
2. removed `module.exports` and used `export default` instead:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export default async function (context, req) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  const res = await fetch("https://www.swyx.io/api/rss.xml");

  const responseMessage = "res:" + res.ok;

  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: responseMessage,
  };
}
```